# How to sort LevelDB by value

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, external-sorting, leveldb

I'm using [leveldb](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/) to store records (key-value), where the key is a 64-bit hash and the value is a double. To make an analogy: think of the 64-bit hash is a unique ID of a customer and the double as an account balance (i.e. how much money they have in their account). I want to sort the database by account balance and list the customers with the highest account balance first. However, the database cannot fit into memory so I have to use some other method for sorting it in order to sort by account balance.

I'm considering using [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/), but it requires that I make a copy of the database into a single flat file, then I can use STXXL to do an external sort (which would make a bunch of smaller files, sort them and then merge them back into another single flat file). Is there a better approach to sorting the data or should I go with the STXXL sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many entries do you have? Could an unsigned 32-bit integer be used as an index (would allow 4,294,967,296 indexes) which could be used to identify how to sort the original array?

i.e. create pairs of 32-bit indexes and account balances, sort on the balances then use the 32 bit indexes to work out what order the original data should be in?

Comment: Then I suppose I could use 64-bit indexes too, right? The key could be `<double, uint64>`...

Comment: I thought you said you couldn't load the full db into memory? I suggested the 32 bit indexes as a way to cut down that information. Is there actually more information than just the 64-bit hash and the amount?

Comment: Correct, I wouldn't have to load them into memory: your suggestion prompted me to use another LevelDB instance for sorting, but in the second LevelDB instance I would use a different key (`<double, uint64>`) and no value. So the keys will be sorted by double and if there are duplicate doubles (which there will be), then the second part of the key will come into play and they will be sorted by the original unique hash. This way, I'll have to copy the data only once.